# How do I continue printing all top 100 movies from rotten tomatoes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made a web scraper, although my for loop isn't printing all the list of movies from the "Top 100 movies of all time" from RottenTomatoes.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/'

# grabbing connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# gather movies
containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"table"})

for container in containers:
    movie_rank_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"bold"})
    movie_rank = movie_rank_container[0].text

    movie_name_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"unstyled articleLink"})
    movie_names = movie_name_container[0].text.strip()

    movie_rating_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"right hidden-xs"})
    movie_rating = movie_rating_container[0].text

    print("Rank: " + movie_rank)
    print("Name: " + movie_names)
    print("Rating: " + movie_rating)
```

Comment: you should use internal `for`-loop to display all values from `findAll`. Or you should find `<tr>` instead of `<table>` and then use loop to check every row separatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use internal `for`-loop to work with every row separatelly

I use `[1:]` to skip header

```
for row in container.findAll('tr')[1:]:
```

---

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/'

# grabbing connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# gather movies
containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"table"})

for container in containers:
    for row in container.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        movie_rank_container = row.findAll("td", {"class":"bold"})
        movie_rank = movie_rank_container[0].text

        movie_name_container = row.findAll("a", {"class":"unstyled articleLink"})
        movie_names = movie_name_container[0].text.strip()

        movie_rating_container = row.findAll("td", {"class":"right hidden-xs"})
        movie_rating = movie_rating_container[0].text

        print("Rank: " + movie_rank)
        print("Name: " + movie_names)
        print("Rating: " + movie_rating)
```

or even using `find()` without `[0]`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/'

# grabbing connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# gather movies
containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"table"})

for container in containers:
    for row in container.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        movie_rank = row.find("td", {"class":"bold"})
        movie_rank = movie_rank.text

        movie_name = row.find("a", {"class":"unstyled articleLink"})
        movie_name = movie_name.text.strip()

        movie_rating = row.find("td", {"class":"right hidden-xs"})
        movie_rating = movie_rating.text

        print("Rank:", movie_rank)
        print("Name:", movie_name)
        print("Rating:", movie_rating)
```

---

Eventually you should use `for`-loop with `zip()` to display all values from all `findAll` - not only `[0]`

But this method can makes problem if items in some rows are empty because this will move other elements in `findAll` and then `zip()` will create wrong pairs (groups) and result will be wrong. It is better to find all rows and work with every row separatelly - like in previous examples.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/'

# grabbing connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# gather movies
containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"table"})

for container in containers:
    movie_rank_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"bold"})
    movie_name_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"unstyled articleLink"})
    movie_rating_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"right hidden-xs"})

    for movie_rank, movie_names, movie_rating in zip(movie_rank_container, movie_name_container, movie_rating_container):
        print("Rank: " + movie_rank.text)
        print("Name: " + movie_names.text.strip())
        print("Rating: " + movie_rating.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

- All of the code can be replaced with [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

  - Read HTML tables into a `list` of `DataFrame` objects.
- `dfl` contains dataframes for `TOP 100 MOVIES OF ALL TIME`, `CERTIFIED FRESH IN THEATERS`, & `TOP 10 DVD RELEASES`

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the web page; dfl will be a list of dataframes (1 for each table on the page)
dfl = pd.read_html('https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/')

# iterate through and display each df
for i, df in enumerate(dfl):
    print(i)  # print the index
    display(df)  # display the dataframe at each index

# display(dfl[2].head())
   Rank RatingTomatometer                     Title  No. of Reviews
0   1.0               96%      Black Panther (2018)             505
1   2.0               94%  Avengers: Endgame (2019)             524
2   3.0               93%                 Us (2019)             527
3   4.0               97%        Toy Story 4 (2019)             437
4   5.0               98%   The Wizard of Oz (1939)             118

# display(dfl[2].tail())
     Rank RatingTomatometer                                             Title  No. of Reviews
95   96.0               97%                  Won't You Be My Neighbor? (2018)             246
96   97.0               99%                                Rear Window (1954)              71
97   98.0               99%                                  Chinatown (1974)              73
98   99.0               99%                        I Am Not Your Negro (2017)             205
99  100.0               90%  Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri (2017)             402
```